# Combining between two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two big queries, individually they both work and produce what I want.

Query 1:

```
SELECT pt.map, pt.time, pt.jumps, pt.id
FROM playertimes pt
WHERE auth = '[U:1:204506329]' AND style = 0 ORDER BY map;
```

(In action, [U:1:204506329] is a variable)

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rank
FROM playertimes pt
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.auth = pt.auth
WHERE pt.time <= (
    SELECT time
    FROM playertimes
    WHERE map = 'bhop_horsepoop_8' AND style = 0 AND auth = '[U:1:204506329]'
    LIMIT 1
) AND pt.map = 'bhop_horsepoop_8' AND pt.style = 0
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1;
```

(Again, [U:1:204506329] and bhop_horsepoop_8 are variables)

The purpose of query 1 is to retrieve a list of `map`s, `time`s, `jump`s and `id`s where `auth` is something I define.

The purpose of query 2, is to find `auth`'s position ('rank') in the `playertimes` table on the defined `map` and `style`. My intention, is to sum both of those to a single query. To receive both what I want in the first query, and then get the `rank` field for every row retrieved in query 1.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT pt.map, pt.time, pt.jumps, pt.id, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
    FROM playertimes pt
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.auth = pt.auth
    WHERE pt.time <= (
        SELECT time
        FROM playertimes
        WHERE map = pt.map AND style = 0 AND auth = '[U:1:204506329]'
        LIMIT 1
    ) AND pt.map = map AND pt.style = 0 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
) rank
FROM playertimes pt
WHERE auth = '[U:1:204506329]' AND style = 0
ORDER BY map;
```

The results ended up being very incorrect!

The following is the resultset of this query (phpMyAdmin):

[image: Query resultset]

As you see, `rank` is always the same and it should change every row. While what I want is for `rank` to get calculated according to the `map` of the same row.

I'm really stuck. Help (and an explanation, if possible) would be very appreciated!

Update: I have tried Mike's solution, this is the query I ended up with:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pt.map, pt.time, pt.jumps, pt.id, pt.auth
    FROM playertimes pt
        WHERE auth = '[U:1:204506329]' AND style = 0
            ORDER BY map
        ) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) rank
            FROM playertimes pt
                LEFT JOIN users u
                    ON u.auth = pt.auth
                        WHERE pt.time <=(
                            SELECT time, auth
                                FROM playertimes
                                    WHERE map = a.map AND style = 0 AND auth = '[U:1:204506329]'
                                        LIMIT 1
  )
        AND pt.map = a.map AND pt.style = 0
            ORDER BY time ASC
                LIMIT 1
                    ) b
    ON a.auth = b.auth;
```

The following is the error MariaDB is returning:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'a.map' in 'where clause'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this one. But, I tried filling `WHERE a.map` with a constant string, this is the output:

```
 #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Which is of course because I tried to select both `time` and `auth` for the operand (while I'm only supposed to select one field), which I have to do otherwise `ON a.auth = b.auth` will throw an error about `b.auth` being an unknown column in the ON clause.

Update 2: I have come to a partial solution, where the query works but `rank` only applies for the `map` I define.

```
SELECT a.map,
       a.time,
       a.jumps,
       a.id,
       a.auth,
       b.rank
FROM
  ( SELECT pt.map,
           pt.time,
           pt.jumps,
           pt.id,
           pt.auth
   FROM playertimes pt
   WHERE auth = '[U:1:204506329]'
     AND style = 0
   ORDER BY MAP ) a
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) rank,
           pt.auth
   FROM playertimes pt
   LEFT JOIN users u ON u.auth = pt.auth
   WHERE pt.time <=
       ( SELECT time
        FROM playertimes
        WHERE MAP = 'bhop_horsepoop_8'
          AND style = 0
          AND auth = '[U:1:204506329]' LIMIT 1 )
     AND pt.MAP = 'bhop_horsepoop_8'
     AND pt.style = 0
   ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1 ) b ON a.auth = b.auth;
```

I couldn't think of a solution that would calculate `rank` for the current row.

Comment: keep the language clean...

Comment: I was deceived!  I was expecting to see big queries.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell whether a simpler version would work, but as a rule two queries with a common field can be combined by simply converting them to work tables and inner joining or left joining.  Have you tried that?  Something like "select * from (query 1) a left join (query 2) b on a.auth = b.auth"?

Comment: Big queries? where?

Comment: @MarcB - this is an actual value in the table. I didn't have the intention to do that, excuse me.

Comment: @MikeChristie I have updated the question after trying your suggestion.

Comment: I see you modified query 2 to include the a.map clause; I wouldn't expect that to work, since it refers to something outside that scope.  Try the same structure, but this time put query 1 and query 2 exactly as they are at the top of your post, with no changes, except that you can remove the order by clauses as they are meaningless inside work tables.

Comment: @MikeChristie when I do it like you tell me to, I get `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.auth' in 'on clause'` as I don't select a.auth anywhere outside the subquery, which is why I need to actually edit it instead of using the original one without changes.